# Vim: region-based highlighting doesn't end at the end of the region

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I want to highlight all the lines starting with a dot as C code:

```
syntax include @CSYN syntax/c.vim
syntax region cSnip matchgroup=Snip start=/^\./ end=/$/ contains=@CSYN
```

It works OK, unless there's an { on the end of the line:

```
.while(1) {
xxx
```

In such case the xxx string is highlighted as if it was an C identifier.

How can I switch C syntax highlighting off at the end of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be preventable by adding the `keepend` keyword to the `:syntax region` definition. Also, since your inclusion only spans a single line, the `oneline` keyword can be added, too.